# Помогите найти ошибку в функции

Tags: c, функции, list

Есть функция для удаления элемента в списке  по его позиции:

```
node * del_node(node *lst, int pos_del)
{
    node *temp = lst; 
    node *temp_r = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    if(pos_del==0)
    {
        lst = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return lst;
    }
    while (temp) 
    {
        if (i == pos_del) 
        {
            temp_r = temp->next;
        }
        if(temp_r)
        {
            temp->next = temp_r->next;
            free(temp_r);
        }
        else temp->next=NULL;
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
    return lst
}
```

Работает криво.Вместо удаления 1 элемента удаляет все элементы кроме него.А при введении 0 происходит краш.Прошу тапками не кидаться только осваиваю списки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотри, при удалении 0-го элемента (т.е. начального) списка всё просто и в твоём коде это нормально реализовано. Если же надо удалять элемент отличный от 0-го, то хитрость заключается в том, что в алгоритме нужно хранить адрес предыдущего элемента (temp_prev) так как при удалении какого-то промежуточного элемента получается так, что *предыдущий элемент от текущего должен указывать на следующий от текущего, а текущий должен быть удалён из памяти!*
[image: drawing]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;

node* del_node (node *lst, int pos_del);
void print_list(node *lst);

int main()
{
    /* Create test list */
    node *node_1 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *node_2 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *node_3 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    node_1->next = node_2; 
    node_1->data = 10;
    node_2->next = node_3;
    node_2->data = 20;
    node_3->next = NULL;
    node_3->data = 30;

    node *lst = node_1;

    /* Before delete */
    print_list(lst);

    /* Test delete */
    lst = del_node(lst, 1);

    /* After delete */
    print_list(lst);

    free(node_1);
    free(node_2);
    free(node_3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

node* del_node(node *lst, int pos_del)
{
    node *temp = lst;
    node *temp_prev = { 0 };
    int i = 0;

    if (pos_del == 0) /* Delete the first element */
    {
        lst = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return lst;
    }
    else /* Delete any but not the first element */
    {
        temp_prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        i = 1;

        while (temp)
        {
            if (i == pos_del)
            {
                temp_prev->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return lst;
            }
            temp_prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void print_list(node *lst) 
{
    int i = 0;
    node *tmp = lst;
    while (tmp) 
    {
        printf("Node %d: Data: %d\n", i, tmp->data);
        i++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

PS: конечно это на совести вызывающего функцию вводить индекс для существующего элемента (т.е. не больший размера списка), так как его проверка нигде не реализована. По хорошему такая проверка, конечно-же необходима, и, при вводе некорретного индекса надо выводить ошибку. Так-же полезно где-то (возможно в отдельной структуре) хранить текущий размер списка, адрес первого элемента и др. полезную инфу, которая облегчит работу со списком.